# Bypass Sudo for some selected commands only

Tags: ubuntu

How to bypass sudo while working with

> mount /dev/nbd0p1 mnt

and

> qemu -nbd /dev/nbd0 /desktop/xyz.vdi

the above mentioned commands only, how can we do this, if you have any idea then please enlighten us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by editing the `/etc/sudoers` file :
add this line to the file :

```
your-username ALL=NOPASSWD: your-command
```

to bypass all commands for all users, add this

```
 ALL ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

Comment: Yeah, I know that but I don't want to actually remove sudo from all the commands, this will compromize my system integrity. I only want to remove it in those command so that i can run those in a script.

Comment: your-username ALL=NOPASSWD: your-command

this will remove sudo only for : your-command

Answer (score 0):

actually you can specify in your sudoers file, not to require password when issueing those two specific commands, like this:

user host = (root) NOPASSWD: /sbin/shutdown
user host = (root) NOPASSWD: /sbin/reboot

here is the source

https://askubuntu.com/questions/159007/how-do-i-run-specific-sudo-commands-without-a-password